# Peak-to-Peak vs Mean Voltage Measurement

Tags: current-measurement, oscilloscope, voltage-measurement

I am using an oscilloscope with 2 probes to measure the average voltage across a resistor over time.

In regard to the measurement modes for the 2 channels on my oscilloscope, I am not sure whether to choose **mean**(average of data values) or **Peak to Peak**(difference between maximum and minimum data values). Maybe it doesn't really matter, but I hope to gain some clarity in this.

Thank you:)

Comment: In English, "mean" is the mathematically accurate term for average. Peak-to-peak is something else altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Mean setting.

The mid-point of the Peak-to-Peak can differ significantly from the mean if the signal is asymmetric (eg a pulse that only occurs occasionally).

Be aware that most oscilloscopes perform the average on the signal displayed on the screen - if there is not an integer number of full cycles the average may not be correct.

For example while displaying a sine wave and 1-1/2 cycles are displayed the average will consist of a full cycle (which will average to zero) together with one half cycle (which will have an non-zero average) so the displayed average will not be zero.

To avoid this error there are two options; either adjust the horizontal time base so that exactly one or two (or any integer number) of cycles are displayed.

Or use the "Cycle Average" that most scopes have. This will calculate the average for complete cycles and give the correct result (zero in this example).